# How to change the file name runtime

Tags: python

I have imported a file using the below command

```
code='IN'
exec "import %s_tmp_file" % code
```

Now i want to use this same imported file for other operations. How to give the file name in that case?

```
str = code_tmp_file.dict # this does not work.
```

Comment: There are two very bad things there: your `IN_tmp_file` module is shadowing the `dict` builtin, and your main module is shadowing the `str` builtin. Use different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `__import__` builtin instead of `exec`:

```
my_module = __import__("%s_tmp_file" % code)
str = my_module.dict
```

See [this page](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) or `help(__import__)` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use `__import__` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)).